# как передать параметр из компонента в само приложение?

Tags: vue.js

Использую Vue.js 
в шаблоне вызываю компонент

```
<message :messages="messages" :messages_id="{{ $messages_id }}"></message>
```

компонент принимает параметр

```
export default {
    props: ['messages', 'messages_id'],
}
```

как передать messages_id из компонента в само приложение в data?

app.js

```
Vue.component('message', require('./components/Message.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data:  {
    messages: [],
    messages_id: 0,
},
mounted(){
    this.fetchMessages(this.messages_id);
},
methods: {
    fetchMessages(messages_id) {
        axios.get('/message/'+messages_id).then(response => {
            this.messages = response.data;
        })
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Во Vue вы **не можете менять props**. Вы можете создать новую переменную в data, передать ей значение из props. Тогда её можно менять. Чтобы передать это значение родительскому компоненту, необходимо использовать `this.$emit('event'[, value])`, а на родительском компоненте отлавливать событие event, перезаписывать значение переменной data. Таким образом передача данных из родительского компонента в дочерний не двучсторонняя, а строго односторонняя, а передавать значения из ребенка родителю можно только событиями. Документация:
[https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Пользовательские](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5) события

```js
Vue.component('my-message', {
  template: '<div v-on:click="idChange">Message id is: {{child_messages_id}}<div>',
  props: ['messages', 'messages_id'],
  data: function () {
    return {child_messages_id: this.messages_id}
    },
  methods: {
    idChange() {
      this.child_messages_id++;
      this.$emit('id-change', this.child_messages_id)
    }
  }
})

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    messages: [],
    messages_id: 0,
  },
  methods: {
    onIdChange(val) {
      this.messages_id = val
    }
  }
  //... fetch data
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1>{{messages_id}}</h1>
  <my-message v-on:id-change="onIdChange" :messages="messages" :messages_id="messages_id"></my-message>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ я не хотел изменять props, я хочу передать начальную переменную, чтоб загружать комментарии после загрузки страницы (при инициализации скрипта), но и Ваш ответ выше тоже очень полезен @larrymacbarry